# Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") Run-time error 429

Tags: ms-office

I am trying to use this code which accesses the file system, which I know works on Windows:

`Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("Macintosh HD:Users:nickname:Documents:myfile.txt", True)`

However, when I run it in Excel for Mac 2016, it gives me this error: Run-time error 429 Object creation with ActiveX component not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the code refers to the scripting library (which is not part of excel).  It is a microsoft/windows component and would not be provided on the MAC.